# How to optimize Google Apps Script Code to prevent maximum execution time exceeded?

Tags: javascript, optimization, google-apps-script

This Google Apps Script Project takes photos from a Google Drive folder and uses these photos to create a slideshow. Basically, it takes the file name as the student's name,  the file as the picture to be inserted into the slideshow, and it also puts the school logo and Grad ${{Current Year}}. I want this script to be able to deal with thousands of photos if possible without exceeding the quota.

Is there a way to optimize this code so it only runs for 1 to 2 mins and be able to deal with 1000 or more photos.

```
function createPresentation() {

  var year, school, name, fileName, colour, foreground, font, nameSize, titleSize, gradSize, schoolLogo, deck;

  year = new Date().getFullYear().toString(); // Current Year

  school = 'High School'; // School Name

  name = "Class of " + year;

  fileName = "Class of " + year + " - " + school; // Class Year

  colour = "#C53023"; // School Colour

  foreground = "#000000"; // Foreground Colour (Black)

  font = "Roboto"; // Font 

  nameSize = 70; // Font size for names

  titleSize = 80; // Font size for title

  gradSize = 33; // Font size for Grad 20..

  schoolLogo = '.../logo.jpg'; // School Logo

  deck = SlidesApp.create(fileName); // Creates the presentation

  title(deck, font, name, colour, school, foreground, titleSize );

  createSlides(deck, schoolLogo, year, gradSize, font);

  createStudents(deck);
}

function title(deck, font, name, colour, school, fcolour, fsize ){

  var [title, subtitle] = deck.getSlides()[0].getPageElements();

  // Class of ${Current Year}
  title.asShape().getText().setText(name);
  title.asShape().getText().getTextStyle().setBold(true).setForegroundColor(colour).setFontSize(fsize).setFontFamily(font);

  // School Name 
  subtitle.asShape().getText().setText(school);
  subtitle.asShape().getText().getTextStyle().setBold(true).setFontFamily(font).setForegroundColor(fcolour).setFontSize(33);

}


function countFiles() {
  // Function to count the number of files in the folder
  var files = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Test").next().getFiles();

  var count = 0;

  while (files.hasNext()){
    count++;
    file = files.next();
  }

return count;
}

function measureImage(){

}


function createSlides(deck, logoURL, year, fontSize, font) {
  // Function to create slides
  var numSlides = parseInt(countFiles()); // Number of files in Graduation folder

  for (var i = 0; i < numSlides; i++) {
  slide = deck.appendSlide(SlidesApp.PredefinedLayout.BLANK);

  var logo = slide.insertImage(logoURL).setTop(322).setLeft(50).setHeight(60).setWidth(80);
  var caption = 'GRAD' + " " + year;
  var shape = slide.insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.TEXT_BOX, 149, 324, 260, 90);  
  var textRange = shape.getText();
  textRange.setText(caption).getTextStyle().setFontSize(fontSize).setFontFamily(font).setBold(true);
}
}

function createStudents(deck){
  // Get names and pictures from file

  var count = 1;

  // Student Names
  var folder = "Test" // Folder Name
  var files = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folder).next().getFiles(); // Get files from folder

  while (files.hasNext()){
    var file = files.next();

    var slide = deck.getSlides()[count]

    // Get and format students' name from file name.
    var studentName = file.getName();
    var studentf = studentName.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')
    var fields = studentf.split('_');
    var firstname = fields[1] ;
    var lastname = fields[0];

    // Place the name on the slide
    var shape = slide.insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.TEXT_BOX, 50, 80, 320, 120);
    var textRange = shape.getText();
    textRange.setText(firstname + '\n' + lastname).getTextStyle().setFontSize(60).setFontFamily('Roboto').setBold(false).setForegroundColor('#C53023');
    var paragraphs = textRange.getParagraphs();
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      var paragraphStyle = paragraphs[i].getRange().getParagraphStyle();
      paragraphStyle.setParagraphAlignment(SlidesApp.ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);  
    }


    // Get the image and set its location.

      var image = slide.insertImage(file.getAs('image/png'));
      var imgWidth = image.getWidth();
      var imgHeight = image.getHeight();
      var pageWidth = deck.getPageWidth();
      var pageHeight = deck.getPageHeight();
      var newX = pageWidth/2. - imgWidth/2.;
      var newY = pageHeight/2. - imgHeight/2.;
      image.setLeft(newX+200).setTop(newY);




    count++;

}
}
```

Every time the script runs, it gets timed out after ~366 seconds (~6.1 mins).

Comment: You want to reduce the process cost of your current script. In the current script, the process time of `createPresentation()` is more than `~366 seconds`. If my understanding is correct, in order to correctly understand your script, can you provide the average process times for each function in the function of `createPresentation()`? By this, at first, how about modifying from the function with the highest cost?

Comment: Must have to do with your `createStudents` `while` loop. You'll want to use `setInterval` for loops that will run too long.

Comment: Also, consider breaking the required performance into chunks and have your function tackle the problem chunkwise.

Comment: See if this article helps from an architectural approach - https://script.gs/bypass-script-execution-timeout-programmatically/